# Alexa Dialog Model Step and dialogState is never in COMPLETED

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I'm implementing an Alexa Dialog Model with an PHP Endpoint.
I used the Alexa doc (https://developer.amazon.com/fr/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html)

Here is my example:
My skill:

> RequestIntent
>
> Utterance : add an {obj} in the bedroom
>
> Slots : {obj} / Slot Filling

Phrase:

> Me : Alexa, Add an object in the bedroom
>
> Alexa : What object do you want to add in bedroom ?
>
> Me : I would like to add a cars in the bedroom
>
> Alexa : You want to add a car in the bedroom ?
>
> Me : Yes

**STEP1:**

> DialogState is STARTED
>
> I use ElicitSlot to set the {obj} slot

**STEP2:**

> dialogState is IN_PROGRESS.
>
> I use ConfirmIntent to ask user to confirm it

**STEP3:**

> > User say yes/no
>
> ConfirmIntent is now set to CONFIRMED/DENIED
>
> BUT still in IN_PROGRESS

dialogState should be COMPLETED because i set all of my slot and intent value right ? So why should not be working in here ?

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your `dialogState` is not `COMPLETE` because you are using `Dialog.ElicitSlot` directive. The `COMPLETED` status is **only possible when you use** `Dialog.Delegate` directive.

More information on controlling the dialog with `Dialog.Delegate` directive [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html#scenario-full-control)

Comment: Thanks for the answer !

Answer (score 1):

DialogState has only the following status:
"STARTED" , "IN_PROGRESS" , "COMPLETED.

The reason why is not completed could be because not all the steps are complete or the IntentRequest has not all the required slot values.

Comment: is there a way to know which step is not complete ? thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

For me, I must enable the **Auto Delegation** option in **Interfaces** from Alexa Developer Console.

> Let Alexa automatically determine and complete each step of the dialog, based on your dialog model. Your skill gets a single IntentRequest when the dialog is complete. You can override this setting at the intent level. [Learn More](https://developer.amazon.com/fr/docs/custom-skills/delegate-dialog-to-alexa.html) about Auto Delegation.

Once all the steps are complete, the skill receives the final `IntentRequest` with `dialogState` set to `COMPLETED`.